# setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build while setting Provider value

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-state

```
class UserModel extends ChangeNotifier{

    User _user;
    
    set setuser(User user)
    {
        _user = user;
        notifyListeners();
    }
    
    User get getuser{
        return _user;
    }
}


class UserLoader extends StatelessWidget
{
    final _db= FireStoreService();
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('HomeScreen'),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _db.getUserDetails()
            builder:(context,futureData){
                if(futureData.state == ConnectionState.done)
                {
                    if(futureData.hasData)
                    {
                        Provider.of<UserModel>.setuser = futureData.data;
                    }
                }
            }
        ),
      );
    }
}
```

I know this is happening because of Provider.of.setuser = futureData.data; as it is calling build function again while the build function is in progress.
I there any alternate way where i can set the values in Provider but not building it specially in the cases where builder is being used.

Comment: try  to do Provider.of<UserModel>(context, listen: false).setuser = futureData.data;

Comment: You can't modify a state inside build/FutureBuilder

Comment: @RemiRousselet Thanks for replying .If we cannot modify the state inside a builder then What could be the alternative approach to set the Providers value if it is dependent on values which comes through some builders

Comment: Make UserModel do the http request and modification instead.

Comment: @RémiRousselet  Thanks